# Add hash to css file names

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

**Background**

- I have two css files - styles.mobile.css and styles.desktop.css
- As the name suggests, I am using two separate css for mobile and desktop
  views
- I inject css dynamically in index.html based on screen size
- Obviously I can't put them in styles.css
- I have attached folder structure screenshot

**Question** 
Is there a way to add hashing to styles.mobile.css and styles.desktop.css when I run ng build --prod

**Code to detect device and inject css**

```js
 private addCss(): void {
    if (this.currentDevice === "desktop") {
      this.document
        .getElementById("theme")
        .setAttribute("href", "styles.desktop.css");
    } else {
      this.document
        .getElementById("theme")
        .setAttribute("href", "styles.mobile.css");
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `index.html` on how you detect it?

Comment: Why don't you use single css and add media query to differentiate css based on screen size?

Comment: I don't see why you can't put them into your `style.css` file. Make a media query and you're good to go.

Comment: @trichetriche Both styles.mobile.css and styles.desktop.css are altogether different. So I decided to have two separate manageable css instead of single giant file.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that you can create a single file that import both separate files, and use media queries to chose which one to use.

Comment: But mobile user will end up downloading desktop css which is never gonna used and vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

Add "ng build --prod --output-hashing all", hash contents of the generated files and append hash to the file name to facilitate browser cache busting

Comment: no it works only for js, it is not adding the hash to our css in angular and it causes issue in the browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your css files on a stylesheet rather than on your `index.html`, first convert your css files to `scss`

**styles.desktop.scss**

```
@media (min-width: 940px) {
   // your styles here
}
```

**styles.mobile.scss**

```
@media (max-width: 940px) and (min-width: 100px) {
  // mobile specific styles here
}
```

Edit you `.angular-cli.json`

Add both scss to `app.styles`

```
"apps": [
  {
    ...
    styles: [
      "styles.desktop.css",
      "styles.mobile.css"
    ]
  }
]
```

`ng build --prod` should automatically produce a hashed and a stylesheet file.

Comment: Thanks for your response but mobile user will end up downloading desktop css which is never gonna used and vice-versa